Creating a bar plot with lower and upper limits
Let say I have below plot
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
dat = rbind(data.frame('Quarter' = as.yearqtr(as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2006-01-01'))), 'Val' = c(10,20,30,40), 'Val_Lower' = c(10,20,30,40) - 5, 'Val_Upper' = c(10,20,30,40)+5, type = rep('A', 4)), 
            data.frame('Quarter' = as.yearqtr(as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2004-01-01', '2006-01-01'))), 'Val' = c(10,20,30,40)-5, 'Val_Lower' = c(10,20,30,40)-5 - 5, 'Val_Upper' = c(10,20,30,40)+5-5, type = rep('B', 4)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Quarter, y = Val)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = type, ymin = Val_Lower, ymax = Val_Upper), alpha = .3)

However instead of continuous ribbon for lower and upper limits, I want to have vertical bar for each dat separately with different type, something like below

Is there any way to achieve this kind of plot?

We could use geom_linerange:
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Quarter, y = Val, color = type)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Val_Lower, ymax = Val_Upper), 
                 alpha = .3, linewidth = 15) +
  geom_point()


Created on 2024-12-23 with reprex v2.0.2
